# Django: static files vs. other data files

Tags: python, django

If I want to display images in a template, the path I specify is relative to the static folder in my app directory. But if I want to load a file from a view function, then the path I specify seems to be relative to the project directory. Should these files all be in the same directory? Or is it typical to separate them out in this way? Is a file loaded by a view function (such as a text file containing human-readable settings) considered to be "static" in the same sense as image, css and js files for rendering my template?

Answer (score 0):

Django supports two different things: static and media files. Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images) are the files that are part of your website. User uploaded content like images or videos are uploaded to `MEDIA_ROOT`. You can use these two settings to control this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/absolute/path/to/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Using dev server, you might need to add this to your URLs,

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Using file upload fields (`FileField`, `ImageField`), you can get the file url using url property which will include the defined `MEDIA_URL`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not mix up true static content with package data files. Among other things, you generally don’t want users to be able to read those data files directly. Instead, place your files somewhere else within your package’s directory, then use [`pkgutil.get_data`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) to read them.